# creating 2D arrays in Java doesn't make sense

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

if `new int[5]` creates an int array of length 5, and `new String[5]` creates a String array of length 5,

then by that logic, shouldn't `new int[3][4]` create an int[3] array of length 4 like {{1,2,3}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,3}}?

Comment: You mean three arrays, each of length four? Also, the default values are `0`.

Comment: As far as I know, in all programming languages, for a two dimensional array, first index represents length of the array and the second index represents length of each sub-array

Comment: So it will only create three array of length four instead four array of length three

Comment: I believe he's asking why `arr[j][k]` creates `j` arrays of length `k` instead of `k` arrays of length `j`. Why isn't `arr[j][k`] equal to `(arr[j])[k]`? Why the switch to a row-column implementation when column-row seems more intuitive in the context of the language?

Answer (score 0):

As phasma said, this question seems to be asking why java switches to 'column-major' during array creation and back to 'row-major' for access. It seems like multidimensional arrays in Java are allocated using a reversed intuition, but then are accessed using the 'correct' intuition.

An `int[][]` should mean an array of arrays of `int`, right? And it does! So when creating an array, you might be thinking like this: `int[][] arr = new (int[3])[4]`. Because it should be an array of size 4 containing arrays of size 3!

However, if you were to use this intuition, you would then have to access the array like this: `(arr[0-3])[0-2]` instead of `(arr[0-2])[0-3]` like you had created the array, and the order would be switched and would be more confusing and hard to debug.

I believe that the reason most languages do this is to keep things consistent and to prevent confusion. You are smart to think this way, since most people would never notice.